# BizTalk Generic WCF Http Receive Location for web services operations returning void

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I'm trying to make a generic BizTalk receive location (WCF-WSHttp) that would **accept any web service call for methods returning "void"**. (The location is generic because BizTalk is forwarding the message to the real service implementation)

I know that true one-way operations are not supported (except for WCF MSMQ), so the operation has [OperationContract(IsOneWay=false)]

I'm able to call the generic service with a WCF client, and BizTalk correctly handles the message. However, BizTalk then returns a response that the client does not recognize, and the clients throws the following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Error in deserializing
>   body of reply message for operation 'MyOperationName'. 
>   **The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).**

This is an example of a response the client would recognize (tested by calling the service implementation directly, without BizTalk as an intermediary):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
     <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1"/>
     <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:102509d6-15c6-4959-9a98-b714d5d16a1f</a:RelatesTo>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
     <MyOperationResponse xmlns="http://mynamespace"/>
   </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

However, here is an example of the response BizTalk returns:

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:9e794c0c-65f0-4807-b1f2-84a30587df9b</a:RelatesTo>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body/>
 </s:Envelope>
```

(I'm using a one-way receive location so I did not have to write any code to have this returned)

This has two differences with the XML the client expects:

- No <a:Action>
- Empty <s:Body>

**I see two ways to resolve that:**

1. Modify the operation contract (C# interface) to expect an empty response/no action instead of what it currently expects.
2. Configure BizTalk to return the XML the  and  the client expects

Any ideas on how to obtain either solution 1 or solution 2?

For solution 1, I tried playing with the [OperationContract(ReplyAction=...)] attribute but could not find a way to make that work.